# Absolutely Continuous and Strictly Increasing on a Subinterval

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A \subset [0,1]$ be a Borel set such that $0 < m(A\cap I) < m(I)$ for every subinterval $I$ of [0,1].

a.  Let $F(x) = m([0,x] \cap A)$.  The $F$ is absolutely continuous and strictly increasing on $[0,1]$, but $F' = 0$ on a set of positive measure.

b. Let $G(x) = m([0,x] \cap A) - m([0,x]\backslash A)$.  Then $G$ is absolutely continuous on [0,1], but $G$ is not monotone on any subinterval of $[0,1].

I am stuck on this problem and would sincerely appreciate help.  Thank you.

Comment: Where are you stuck? Can you see $F$ and $G$ are absolutely continuous and $F$ is strictly increasing?

Comment: @richard:  I actually cannot see this.  Could you please explain why this is so?  Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, it seems that you are not quite familiar with the concepts involved in the question, so I have no idea how to provide a comprehensive answer to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll get you rolling on part (a).

$F$ is actually Lipschitz. To see this, without loss of generality assume $x > y \in [0,1]$. Then we have
$$(A \cap [0,y]) \cup (A \cap (y,x]) = A \cap [0,x],$$
and since these are disjoint sets 
$$m(A \cap [0,y]) + m(A \cap (y,x]) = m(A \cap [0,x]).$$
Hence,
$$|F(x) - F(y)| = |m(A \cap [0,x])-m(A \cap [0,y])| = |m(A \cap (y,x])| < |x-y|.$$