# Existence of nowhere monotone, absolutely continuous function?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, absolute-continuity

The following is Exercise 7:5.3 from Bruckner's Real Analysis:

> Apply Theorem 7.22 to an appropriately chosen function $f$ to prove
> that there exists an absolutely continuous function $F$ that is nowhere
> monotonic. That is,for every $c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a≤c<d≤b$, $F$ is
> not monotonic on $[c, d]$.

> **Theorem 7.22** Let $f$ be Lebesgue integrable on $[a, b]$, and let $F(x)= \int_a^x f dλ$ for $x \in [a,b]$. Then $F$ is differentiable at almost every point, and $F'=f$ almost everywhere.

How can I apply Theorem 7.22 to do the exercise? Also there seem to be [not an easy function](https://p300.zlibcdn.com/dtoken/28b368254cc64f69428cfc2d60136a32) to construct (Section 4). And how part (b) of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252610/absolutely-continuous-and-strictly-increasing-on-a-subinterval) is absolutely continuous and how it is nowhere monotone?

Comment: So have you tried to find the function $f$ such that $$\lambda( \{ f>0\}\cap[c,d] )>0$$ and  $$\lambda( \{ f<0\}\cap[c,d] )>0$$ for all nontrivial interval  $[c,d] \subset [a,b]$?

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen, that was exactly my thought too! But no function came to my mind being AC

Comment: Why you need $f$ to be AC? Isn't it $F$ that has to be AC?

Comment: Anyways, when you finish your proof ( I don't think this question is hard for you if you have the idea), it would be nice to post it on MSE. It would be a good reference for later as I didn't find any question same as yours on MSE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

- Consider a Borel set $E$ such that for any open interval $I\subset \mathbb{R}$, $0<\lambda(E\cap I)<\lambda(I)$. You might've constructed such set $E'$ before for in $[0,1]$ with the desired property for intervals $I\subset[0,1]$. The set $E=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}(E'+n)$ will do.
- Notice that $E^c:=\mathbb{R}\setminus E$ has a similar property. Indeed,
  $$\lambda(I)=\lambda(I\cap E)+\lambda(I\cap E^c)$$
  and since $0<\lambda(E\cap I)<\lambda(I)$, we obtain that
  $0<\lambda(I\cap E^c)<\lambda(I)$.
- Define $F(x)=\int^x_0\Big(\mathbb{1}_E-\mathbb{1}_{E^c}\Big)\,d\lambda$. $F$ is absolutely continuous and $F'=\mathbb{1}_E-\mathbb{1}_{E^c}$ $\lambda$-a.s.. Since $E$ and $E^c$ are dense, no interval of positive length has fixed signed, so $F$ is not monotone in $I$.

---

If you have not worked on the existence of sets such as $E'$, let me know and I can sketch a construction for you.

Check if $F$ passes muster. Otherwise let me know to either fix or remove this post.

Comment: Yes, on MSE (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57317/construction-of-a-borel-set-with-positive-but-not-full-measure-in-each-interval) and Ex-2:13.9 of Bruckner's book!

Comment: @There you go. I remember it has to do with construction of fat cantor sets put together in a clever way. Anyway, now that you can look at the details about the existence of such sets $E$, see if the function $F$ that I defined pass muster.

Comment: Why $E$ and $E^c$ are dense? How denseness of $E$ and $E^c$ results in "*no interval of positive length has fixed signed*"?

Comment: They are dense pecans they intersect every open set (in fact  $\lambda(E\cap I)>0$ for all open intervals, so $E\cap I\neq\emptyset$ for all open intervals.

Comment: If $F$ were monotone in an interval $J$, then the derivative $F'$ there would be either nonnegative a.s. in$J$ or nonpositive a.s in $J$. But  or negative, $J$ contains points in $E$ and $E^c$ (with positive mass) so $\lambda(\{F'>0\}\cap J)>0$ and $\lambda(\{F'<0\}\cap J)>0$. $F'$ takes values $1$ and $-1$ with positive probability, that will give you a contradiction.